# error connecting Power BI enterprise gateway on an azure machine

Tags: azure, ssas, powerbi

I have created a virtual machine on Azure using Image SQL Server Data Center for SQL Server 2014, and created some SSAS cubes on that machine. I am able to access cubes from management studio. I want to access those cubes from Power Bi. I have installed Power Bi gateway on that machine, and connected cubes using live connect method. I further installed Power Bi Enterprise gateway to enable refresh of my cubes to Power BI cloud. Now when I am trying to connect  to SSAS on Azure machine using PBI Gateway I am not able to connect, it gives me error "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request." On the other hand when I am trying to connect to SQL Server database engine on the same machine from PBE gateway, I am able to connect without any problem. The azure machine is not part of a domain yet, is this may be a reason why I am getting error connecting to SSAS instance from Power BI gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this machine an active directory domain controller, and so this machine is now part of an active directory. Now I am able to connect SSAS instance on this machine to PBI Enterprise gateway, but my problem did not end here, I am still not able to refresh my dataset which I have sourced from the SSAS cube on the same machine. I am getting error "Data source access error. Please contact gateway administrator"

Further I added a new user to Active directory, with same name as I was having an account in Power BI. I further changed UPN of that user in Active directory to that of my Power BI User. Let say name of my domain was domain, and upn was domain.local, and new user I created in AD was NDubey@domain.local, I chnaged the UPN to NDubey@ABC.com, as this was my login name in Power BI. After that I was able to see data in my datasets populated from SSAS cubes.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the Network Interface for the VM is using the expected Network Security Group, and the Network Security Group has the correct Inbound and Outbound Security Rules for the ports used by the PBI Gateway.